# Prepend the same string to all items in a list

Tags: python

Have done some searching through Stack Exchange answered questions but have been unable to find what I am looking for.

Given the following list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How would I create:

```
a = ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4']
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#list-displays):

```
[f'hello{i}' for i in a]
```

A list comprehension lets you apply an expression to each element in a sequence. Here that expression is a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting), incorporating `i` into a string starting with `hello`.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> [f'hello{i}' for i in a]
['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4']
```

Comment: For Python3.6+, can also use f-strings: `[f'hello{i}' for i in a]`.

Comment: @GinoMempin: Yup. I'd go so far as to say it is the preferred option these days.

Answer (score 11):

One more option is to use [built-in map function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
a = range(10)
map(lambda x: 'hello%i' % x, a)
```

Edit as per WolframH comment:

```
map('hello{0}'.format, a)
```

Comment: Or use `map('hello{0}'.format, a)`, in particular if you don't know `lambda` yet. Note: in Python 3.x `map` does not return a `list` (but another iterable object, which can be converted into a `list` by using `list()`.

Comment: @WolframH superb tip!

Answer (score 1):

use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays):

```
In [1]: a = [1,2,3,4]

In [2]: ["hello" + str(x) for x in a]
Out[2]: ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4']
```

Comment: Is this a more or less pythonic way than the first answer? I find it a little easier to read. This is essentially the same as the format method under the hood?

Comment: can't say if it's pythonic, but it requires conversion of `int` to `string` first which can be easily handled by `format()`, so go for the `format()` based answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `%` instead of `format()`

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> ['hello%s' % i for i in a]
['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4']
```