# Adding string in dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

To convert two lists into dictionary, we can use `dict(zip(listA, listB))`

```
listA = ['Jones', 'John', 'Jack']
listB = [50, 35, 40]

dict(zip(listA, listB))
>>>>{'Jack': 40, 'John': 35, 'Jones': 50}
```

But what can I do to achieve something like this?

```
>>>>{'Jack': 'Age:40', 'John': 'Age:35', 'Jones': 'Age:50'}
```

I tried `dict(zip(listA, str('Age:')+listB))`, but got this `TypeError: must be str, not list`

Thank you for those who provided a solution. It's appreciated.

Comment: Your desired output is not valid python

Comment: "something like this" meaning "a syntax error"?

Comment: From what I see in your posting and the comments, you're getting down-voted because what you want for a result is not legal Python, and your follow-up questions on output format could be answered by looking up the topic.  That's why *I* down-voted.

Comment: @Prune, thanks for your explanation. I believe the downvote is towards my question (as it shouldn't be related to my follow-up comment). Python is powerful and we can achieve however we want, the perfect example is there is actually a solution for my question provided by A.Rose. And most importantly, I asked question with my effort of trying to work it out although I had no clue on solving it. And at a minimum, it is Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable. I'm speaking up because unreasonable people like to abuse. Anyway, thanks for your explanation, I'll be more cautious.

Comment: Best of all, you updated the question so that you ask for syntactically legal output.  I've retracted my closure vote and reversed the down-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331419/prepend-the-same-string-to-all-items-in-a-list/13331424), you can use a map:

```
map('Age{0}'.format, listB)
```

so:

```
res = dict(zip(listA, list(map('Age:{0}'.format, listB))))
```

but it's not very readable, imho.

Comment: Thanks! It is perfect!

Comment: glad to help - I recommend that you do take a look at the other stackoverflow question; the answers have a bit more detail and some other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Your output is not valid Python syntax.

The best you can do is create a nested dictionary via a comprehension:

```
listA = ['Jones', 'John', 'Jack']
listB = [50, 35, 40]

res = {x: {'Age': y} for x, y in zip(listA, listB)}

# {'Jack': {'Age': 40},
#  'John': {'Age': 35},
#  'Jones': {'Age': 50}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to remove the `{}` inside the dictionary?

Comment: @Karma, No. The characters `{` and `}` are not part of the dictionary. They are just there to denote the existence of a dictionary in string representation. So, no, you can't.

Comment: Thanks. And is there a way to not display the `{}` when I call them as it now shows `{'Age': 40}`?

Comment: For `print`, sure, I suggest you search on SO - there are many identical questions.

Comment: Oh yes, just found it! Thanks a lot!